# How do people manage error numbers for SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I'm not sure this is the right place to ask.

I have a lot of stored procedures in my SQL Server database and most of them `THROW` errors. How do people manage to keep track of those error numbers (for THROW statements)?

Like, for example, part of stored procedure:

```
if not exists (select id from ilgVW_Groups 
               where id = @catId and id.IsDescendantOf(someFunc()) = 1)
begin
    declare @errMsg varchar(60);
    set @errMsg = 'Instance category with Id=' + @catId + ' does not exist';

    throw 90131, @errMsg, 1; -- ===> *** HERE ***
end
```

There are a lot of these `THROW` statements and every one of them need an error number (90131 in my example).

I'm having a hard time keeping track of those numbers.

Comment: If you're using a different number for each THROW across your entire db then you probably need to maintain a table or a reference document somewhere.  I personally only keep them unique within the same stored procedure since I know what the failing procedure is.

Comment: It depends. They represent different errors, but those errors might be used in different stored procs. They're unique across set of procedures (for one type of entity, for example).

Comment: I guess I should create a table to keep them all in one place and some stored proc to get those values by name, for example.

Comment: It's not advised to use raiserror instead of throw.  From the docs: `The RAISERROR statement does not honor SET XACT_ABORT. New applications should use THROW instead of RAISERROR.`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @squillman, where did you see RAISERROR in my question or comments???

Comment: My comment about RAISERROR was in response to a now deleted comment that suggested you use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all the Db is basically a project in a repo (with version tracking, etc), I ended up with the PowerShell script which just returns me a table with [errCode, errMsg]:

```
errCode errMsg
------- ------
  60000 Partition can not be NULL
  60000 Partition can not be NULL
  60000 Partition can not be NULL
  60000 Partition can not be NULL
  60001 Culture can not be NULL
  60001 Culture can not be NULL
  60002 tagId must <> 0
  60002 tagId must <> 0
  60002 tagId must <> 0
  60003 tagName can not be NULL
  60003 tagName can not be NULL
  60004 Can not overwrite tag with the same Id and CultureName. Use different culture.
  60005 Can''t delete by tag name because there the name is used in multiple cultures
...
```

Here's the PowerShell script that extracts all `THROW` statements, if you need it:

```
Clear-Host
Push-Location

Set-Location $pathToYourDbProject

Write-Host `n`nAll error codes and messages:`n

Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.sql" -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Attributes -ne "Directory" } | ForEach-Object {
   Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -Pattern "^\s*throw (\d{5}),\s*'(.+)'.*$" | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "^\s*throw (\d{5}),\s*'(.+)'.*$", '$1, $2' } | ForEach-Object { [PSCustomObject]@{
         errCode = [int]$_.Substring(0, 5)
         errMsg  = $_.Substring(7)
      } }
} | Sort-Object -Property errCode

Pop-Location
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your custom message to `sys.messages` using [`sp_AddMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addmessage-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Errors without parameters can be signaled with [`Throw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Errors with parameters can be signalled by using [`FormatMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/formatmessage-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to insert the parameter values and `Throw` to signal the error.

Comment: No, that's not going to work in SQL Azure.

Comment: @alvipeo If `azure` is a requirement then you _might_ want to add it to your question as a tag.

Comment: @alvipeo Azure SQL Server does support `Throw` and `FormatMessage`, it is "only" missing `sp_AddMessage` and any means to manage custom _status_ messages. `FormatMessage` doesn't require that the message template come from `sys.messages`, so you could implement your own message table. You might consider adding a shorthand string that is a bit more memorable, e.g. `'InstCatNotEx'` that you can use to look up both the message number and text. That allows you to update messages and support multiple languages while still having a stable value in the code.